# Django imports are failing after nesting apps in an apps folder

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

**Here is what I did**:

- I wrapped my 12 Django apps in an `apps` folder in my Django project.
- I added `sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))` in settings.py (before `INSTALLED_APPS` declaration) sothat I don't need to specify the `apps` folder when importing my apps.
- I changed every 12 `apps.py` files to set `name = apps.myappname`
- `INSTALLED_APPS` are still defined with `myappname` (not `apps.myappname`)

**Here is what I have so far**:

- Code works normally
- Unit tests, when run app by app, 100% works for the 12 apps.
- Unit tests, when run as a whole, at some point of execution, fail with errors like this one:

  `ImportError: Failed to import test module: apps.badges.tests
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
      module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
      __import__(name)
    File "/vagrant/fugo/fugoproj/apps/badges/tests.py", line 10, in <module>
      from .factories import BadgeFactory
    File "/vagrant/fugo/fugoproj/apps/badges/factories.py", line 6, in <module>
      from .models import Badge
    File "/vagrant/fugo/fugoproj/apps/badges/models.py", line 51, in <module>
      models.Model):
    File "/home/ubuntu/fenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
      "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
  RuntimeError: Model class apps.badges.models.Badge doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Here is the **badges/factories.py** file in error:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import factory
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Badge
# some code
```

On every test which fails, it seems related to the relative import for the model (`from .models import SomeModel`). If I replace this with `from myappname.models import SomeModel`, this solve the error.
Any idea on something wrong in my code? I'd like to keep my relative imports.
How to explain it does not fail when running tests app by app?
Thanks.

Comment: `/vagrant/fugo/fugoproj/apps/badges/models.py` confused with `/home/ubuntu/fenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/`  when call `models.Model` at line 51?

Comment: `from django.db import models` this line at `/vagrant/fugo/fugoproj/apps/badges/models.py`?